# Cannot make new meeting requests in outlook 2016 but can in outlook 2010 with exchange 2013 Rooms calendars?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2016, exchange-2013

This one is a tough one. I am able to make "New Meeting Requests" in outlook 2010, but this option is grayed out in office 2016. The Mailbox enabled room calendar was created in exchange 2007 and then migrated to exchange 2013. All the Mailbox enabled rooms with calendars are grayed out in office 2016. All Employees have the permissions to write to the calendars, according to the permissions tab. I'm a little stuck and need help. can someone point me in the right direction?

More Details:

- Can create events in rooms which are free during that time slot. Rooms that are not free during that time slot do not show. The room in question does not show even during free times.
- The mailbox resource calendar is set to the correct time zone.
- We only have exchange 2013. All other versions of exchange has been shutdown.
- I have checked permissions and the permissions are correct. However, I can not make new meeting requests in outlook 2016, but can in OWA and Exchange 2010.

Comment: Can you reproduce the same via OWA? Is Exchange 2007 still in your environment or fully removed? Can you reproduce the issue on a PC which isn´t AD joined (and therefore no GPO in place)?

Comment: I am unable to make meeting requests in OWA for one calendar. Only free calendars show. When i change the time and date to a free time and date on the calendar, I still cannot select the room I am looking for. However free rooms can be added to. There are 4 other rooms setup like this one room which is accessible. If a computer is not part of the domain, it can not reach any domain resources. The exchange 2007 is no longer in network, only our 2 mail cas for 2013 is on the network.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is; education. I was unaware of how Microsoft changed appointment calendars. Ways to make appointments:

1. Click Calendars
2. Click New Meeting
3. Click To and select the room in question.
4. Place subject and information you wish for the meeting.
5. click scheduling assistant to see the free times.
6. select a free time.
7. Press Send. It will add it to your calendar and the room's calendar.

How I was trying it was right clicking the date and select new meeting. This only works with public calendars in office 2016. This is a room resource mailbox, and the above method works for those.